# Reset the text on a button in Javafx through the use of a task continously

Tags: java, javafx

Alright, I need to be able to reset the text of a button or a label in javafx continuously.  I had assumed that the correct plan of action for this was to use the concurrency package and use a task. I'm making an idle game and the one last thing I need to figure out how to do before I can really get cracking away at this is to update the currency without having to click a button.  The value for the currency is constantly updated on its own and I know that part works but I need to show this on the GUI.  At the moment my task looks something like this...

```
Task task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override public Void call() {

            while (true) {

                    update(m, this);  // updates text fields for some buttons
                }


            }


        }


    };
```

I'm getting a bunch of string errors that point to each of the setText lines in the update method.

Comment: In what way do you need it reset continuously? When en event triggers/completes or per time interval or something else? Please print the error you receive as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
protected Void call() throws Exception {
        updateMessage("Execution starts");
        //your code
        updateMessage("Execution completed");
}
```

You might use your `Button`'s textProperty() method to bind with the message that your task updates. Something like this.

```
button.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I actually managed to finally figure it out own my own.  Okay, so here's what I needed to do.  Inside my update method I needed to place a Platform.runLater that then calls my update method inside of the run method.

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

                update(m, this);

            }

    });
```